# Creating a custom ArrayAdapter and filling a ListView with a requested Json using Volley

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

I have been stuck with this exercise for way too long.

I've been given some part of the code and i had to write the rest of it.

First of all, i got a VolleyManager class that helps with some Volley tools (like adding to request queue). Then another Gson class that helps parsing the requested Json.

This is the code for the UserListFragment, where there are two buttons. One for populating the list, one for clearing it, and the list itself below those two buttons.

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String USERS_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bengui/volleytest/master/json/users.json";
private static final String TAG = UserListFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private View view;
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
private Button requestButton;
private Button cleanButton;
private ListView listView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, null);

    // UI Elements
    requestButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.request_btn);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_users);
    requestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listAdapter = new ListAdapter(view.getContext());
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    });

    cleanButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clean_btn);
    cleanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listView.setAdapter(null);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

This is the personalized adapter i made to fill the elements on the list.

```
   public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        VolleyManager volleyManager;
        List<User> list;

        public ListAdapter(Context context){
            super(context,0);
            volleyManager = VolleyManager.getInstance(getActivity());

            requestButton.setEnabled(false);

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    USERS_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            list = parseUserList(response.toString());
                            requestButton.setEnabled(true);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            Log.d(TAG, "JSON response error : " + error.getMessage());
                            requestButton.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
            );
            volleyManager.addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

            View listItemView = convertView;

            if (null == convertView) {
                listItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.fragment_list_item,
                        parent,
                        false);
            }

            // Pick an element of the list and fill the UI textViews.
            User user = list.get(position);

            TextView nombre = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            TextView apellido = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.user_last_name);
            TextView edad = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.user_age);

            // Update views
            nombre.setText(user.getName());
            apellido.setText(user.getLastName());
            edad.setText(user.getAge());

            return listItemView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parses a users json array into a users list.
     *
     * @param jsonArray
     *
     * @return Users list
     */
    private List<User> parseUserList(String jsonArray) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Declares the list type
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();

        List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);

        return userList;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this isn't working. Maybe i don't completely understand how Adapters work and i'm making a wrong call on the button click listener?

I have been trying to figure this out for over a week. **Made some progress!** but still can't make it work.

Any input is welcome.

edit: Forgot the .xmls

This is the layout for the fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_user_list"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/request_btn"
    android:text="@string/request_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clean_btn"
    android:text="@string/clean_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_users"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout for the listview items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_last_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it not showing the list?

Comment: Yes, shows nothing on the display. The data is retrieved though.

Comment: Did you check that getView is called after your list variable is populated?

Comment: Also, in your layout for list view items, should your LinearLayout orientation be horizontal since the child views have width="match_parent"?

Comment: I think getView is not being called, but im not sure where should be called at all.. ! Will keep researching. 

About the LinearLayout, you are right, their width is wrong. Will fix that too so everything shows up. Thanks man!

Comment: if that's the case, make sure your list variable isnt empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to use recycler_View...
Recycler_View can manage many things you don't need to worry about them...

Comment: RecyclerView is a topic i need to study after... i thought it was something that only improved performance by creating less list items?

Comment: Try this in your onCreate() method...ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, tempList);

Comment: I think that line is for when every list item has only one text view. 

In this case every item on the list has 3 textViews, thats why i had to make a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse a Json into a listView do the Following Steps:
1- Create a class will hold the data from the json Object like this:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String last_name;
    String age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

2- Create an Class and name it  Adapter to set it into listview like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<Person> persons;
   private TextView userName ;
    private TextView  lastName;
    private TextView age ;

    public Adapter(Activity activity, List<Person> items){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.persons=items;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return persons.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



            if(inflater==null){
                inflater=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            if(convertView ==null){
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

            }

        userName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        lastName=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        age=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);

        Person person=persons.get(position);

        userName.setText("Name:"+person.getName());
        lastName.setText("LastName:"+person.getLast_name());
        age.setText("Age"+person.getAge());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

3- Inside the fragment that you want to populate the listview Elements ( I used the same link for json in this Fragment and it works successfully) :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersonFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String JSON_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bengui/volleytest/master/json/users.json";
    public static List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    public static Adapter adapter;

    public PersonFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.persons_listView);
        adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(),personList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        setListViewData();

        return  view;
    }

    private void setListViewData() {


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Person person =new Person();
                            person.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                            person.setLast_name(obj.getString("last_name"));
                            person.setAge(obj.getString("age"));

                            personList.add(person);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
            // setArrayListLength(titles);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+titles.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            //).show();

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array2");
            }
        });
        // add json array request to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);


    }
}
```

4- Create inside Layout folder custom_layout.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="userName"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="userName"
            android:textSize="20dp"
           android:paddingTop="10dp"

            />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="userName"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

5- Create another xml resource inside the Layout folder and name it your_fragment_layout.xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/persons_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp"
        ></ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally don't forget this dependency  to add them in Your project gradle

```
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
```

Also don't Forget to add the Internet Permission to your Your manifest file like this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I Tested this Fragment and it works Successfully. Hope this helped you.

Comment: Hey thanks for all of this. When i copy pasted it works . I only had to remove a parameter from the json request (the Request.Method.GET parameter is not needed because it's automatically called from it's own constructor, even though i think the line of code you gave me should work anyway).

Still i will try to make it work from a button, now that i have some working code! 

Thanks again man !